# Implement login page outside of ngroute

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

I have an angularjs site with ngroute to control the link navigation. I build a body template with bootstrap nav bar an other things, and inside the body of the template I put a ng-view object to show the content of my side.

Now I want to wrap a login page outside of it. The problem is, if I route with the $routeProvider to the login page, it will be nested in the ng-view, and that's wrong (because all other content is visible).

For the login page, I followed this tutorial: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx

When I call the login page directly, the URL looks like '/login.html#/login' and that's a bit weird. The regular URL for the main page are like '/#/users'

How do I build that both ist possible? (redirect to login page and main page)?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue. One of you found a solution? This is my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625426/login-page-without-index-html-design-ngroute-angularjs. Thank you!