# Login Page without Index.html Design - ngRoute (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I'm using `ngRoute` to do the routing of my AngularJS application (myApp) but I have a problem: I don't know how to NOT APPLY my `index.html` design (with all my sidebars) to my `login.html` page, which seems to be applied by default if it is defined as a view. I want a simple design for my `login.html` page: only two fields to fill out, without the design of my `index.html`, which is applied to all the views in myApp. Thereby, I don't know how to do my routing to accomplish such task. Thank you very much.

**<-- This is a sample of how I do my routing in myApp (for only one view - "/view1") -->**

**Sample of `app.js`:**

```
'use strict';
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'ngResource',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ngCookies',
'myApp.view1',
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

**For each view there is a .js file associated where I defined its routing and controllers. For instance, for view "/view1" - `view1.js`:**

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])

 .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
   });
 }])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
// something
}]);
```

**And a sample of my `index.html`:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <script src="view1.js"></script>
  <-- MORE SCRIPTS ARE LOADED --> 
 </head>
 <body class="hamburg" ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
  <-- SIDEBARS ARE DEFINED -->
  <div id="content-wrapper">
   <div class="page-content">

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="widget">
         <div class="widget-body">
          <div ng-view></div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: A real bare bones approach would be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/u2um2yeq/

Note, there is more that needs to be done to make that fiddle login secure, like using services to validate a user or token on each request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the situation above looks like you want two **page layout** (page design or page template), the first one is now used in `index.html`, and the second one you want to use in `login.html` which just has two fields to fill out. So `angular-ui/ui-router` (doc url: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) could be the solution to this issue.

The idea behind that is `ui-router` has a very powerful tool named `ui-view` which you can see it as a layout or template. So when the path is on any page other than login page like `/index` or `/home` use one `ui-view`, and on `/login` page then use another different `ui-view`.

For a rough example:
index.html page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view="layout"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I assume you will reuse the head part, so just wrap every thing from the body in the original `index.html` and put into the new `index.html`. Same to the login page `login.html`.

config file:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('index', {
      url: '/index',
      views: {
          layout: {
              templateUrl: "/path/to/index.html"
          }
      },
      controller: 'indexController'
  }

  .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      views: {
          layout: {
              templateUrl: "/path/to/login.html"
          }
      },
      controller: 'loginController'
})
```

So what does the code above do is very similar to what you did with `$routeProvider`, it defines on which `url` use which `controller` and to load which `view`.

Hope this can help you, if any question let me know please.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best solution. I updated my routing with ui-router and it's now working. Thank you very much.

Comment: very glad to help you :)

Comment: I had similar issue.I tried the above code.But only master page which contains headers and footers are loading.The content page is not loading.<div ui-view="layout"></div> is not working.@David do you have any idea?

Comment: Homepage is working but if i redirect to login page master page is also loading in the login page.I dont want index.html page design inside login page

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your login page as a diferente ngApp, store your sesion on the localSotarge in case of a successfull login and then redirect to you main ngApp.

In your main ngApp, validate if a session exists in the localStorage and redirecto to the loginApp if it dont.

I know it sounds a bit like overdoing stuff, but I have not found any other solution in my 3 years working with AngularJS. Now, keep in mind that this is necesary because you need to NOT TO APPLY your index.html, and the only way to do that is using another ngApp.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be a good solution to my problem but I think that the easiest solution is probably to update my routing with angular-ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

Routing is used for injecting views in angular SPA. What I get from from your question is you need a login dialog. 
For that you may look `ngDialog` or `uibDialog`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to load new layout. I understand, for login and for application there is mostly different layout. This operation is equal to redirecting page to new location. With new angular app and controllers for login. You can use:

`$window.location.href="new/layout/template"`.

Read more [@ Angular Dev Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location).